# Sorted array using nested loops and substring method (C#)

Tags: c#, sorting, input, output, substring

I am trying to manually sort an array using string inputs that end with a number which I want to sort from highest to lowest.

For example I can start with this output:
,Name1: 1540
,Name2: 2660
,Name3: 80
,Name4: 380

And in the end it should look like this:
,Name2: 2660
,Name1: 1540
,Name4: 380
,Name3: 80

```
private string[] OrderHighToLow(string[] data)
    {
        string temp;
        for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < i; y++)
            {
                if (int.Parse(data[y].Substring((data[y].IndexOf(':') + 2))) > int.Parse(data[i].Substring((data[i].IndexOf(':') + 2)))) 
                {
                    temp = data[i];
                    data[i] = data[y];
                    data[y] = temp;
                }
            }
        }
        return data;
    }
```

This is what I have tested. According to me, this should work, but the point is it doesn't, the application just crashes. So, if anyone here can figure out why that may be, I would be very thankful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Define "just crashes". Do you get a stack trace of some kind?

Comment: Why not do data.OrderBy(d=>-int.Parse(d)).ToArray()

Comment: System.ArgumentOutOfRangeExceptions: start index must not be greater than the length of the string

Comment: Wrap your if statement in a try catch and put a breakpoint inside of the catch area. When you hit this you'll be able to see what data looks like. I suspect it's one of your substrings

Comment: @NigelBess I am making this for my first term in a programming course and we haven't learned about arrow functions yet.

Comment: cause you're doing + 2 on a string that doesn't have 2 characters after the colon

Comment: @LukasMannerstål: That means that some of the strings in your `data` doesn't look how you think it does. Put a breakpoint on the entry to your function and inspect that data. Most likely with the way you're parsing it, you're ending up with an empty string or something.

Comment: When I manually parse your inputs and pass them into your code, it's not throwing an exception: it's just sorting ascending rather than descending. I'm voting to close based on this being not reproducible.

Comment: Same as StriplingWarrior said, doesn't seem to produce an error. How are you calling the "OrderHighToLow" and passing the parameters?

Comment: I am calling it like this: unSortedArray = OrderHighToLow(unSortedArray) which should just exchange the unsorted array with the sorted one

Comment: But how are you getting `unSortedArray` in the first place? And what are the actual values inside it at the point where this method is called?

Comment: By the way, passing strings around that you expect to be parsed in a special way and have specific meaning like this is an example of _primitive obsession_. Ideally you should parse these strings into an object structure upstream of this point, and take those objects as your argument and output instead of strings. If you'd done that, you'd have caught this problem in the step where you parse the values rather than thinking there's a problem with your sorting code.

Comment: Oh, yeah. Sorry for that. I am kind of new to windows forms. Now I have found the solotion. Apparently when importing the values into my array one of the slots become empty because of a auto generated empty row in the data (txt-file). It was not easy to spot so I just assumed there was some fault in my code.

Answer (score 1):

your comparison is worng

```
int.Parse(data[y].Substring((data[y].IndexOf(':') + 2)))
```

less than Not greater than

```
 if (int.Parse(data[y].Substring((data[y].IndexOf(':') + 2))) < int.Parse(data[i].Substring((data[i].IndexOf(':') + 2))))
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do the job with the Help of `System.Linq`:

```cs
private string[] OrderHighToLow(string[] data)
{
    //create a temporary dictionary, which makes sorting easier
    var tmpMap = new Dictionary<string, int>();
    foreach (var item in data)
    {
        //split the string 
        var elems = item.Split(":");
        //add string and int pair to the dictionary
        tmpMap.Add(elems[0], int.Parse(elems[1]));
    }

    //sort Dictionary by value and use select to rebuild the string, then convert it back to an array
    return tmpMap.OrderByDescending(x => x.Value).Select(x => $"{x.Key}: {x.Value}").ToArray();
}
```

Hope this helps.